# Javascript: getElementbyID width issues

Tags: javascript, html

following a javascript tutorial on youtube, learning the basics.

Have the following code here which line for line is the same as I see it (excluding maybe variable names).
Tried to debug and see that alert and console messages go through but the document.getElementByID.style.width seems to get me nothing.

width is a defined variable (yes should have named it differently to not clash with keyname width but did change name and same results anyway).
Having console.log as the outputs.
Outputs width fine and it does increment.
the actual image doesn't move an inch however.
Can't see any typos.
The code is exactly the same as the tutorial.
Looked it over for nearly an hour already.
Any help is appreciated.  It's not much, very basic, but I don't want to skip out on understanding why something doesn't work, thanks.

```js
let width =200;
let diff = 2;

let intervalID = 0;

function increase() {
  intervalID = setInterval(zoomIn, 20);
}

function zoomIn() {
  if (width < 400) {
    width = width + diff;
    document.getElementById("img2").style.width = width;
    console.log(width);
    console.log(document.getElementById("img2").style.width);
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="img2" onmouseover="increase()" onmouseout="decrease()" src="/Images/image.png" alt="img" width="200" />
```

Comment: The error very clearly says "Uncaught ReferenceError: width is not defined"  - because you need to define or assign to a variable called width before testing such a var

Comment: So `let width = 200;`  for example or `let width = document.getElementById("img2").style.width || 200;` to give a default if none

Comment: Yes as mentioned already have a let width=200; up top as a global.  just not included in code snippet for posting sorry.  Added now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: Now `diff is not defined`. Please, test your example code before showing it to the community.

Comment: sorry added all variables now.  For HTML ignore decrease function, that is not required yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object.style.width property gets an String composed by the number + the px word **not only a number**, also if you dont have the decrease method you have going to have an undefined exception:

```
let width =200;
let diff = 2;

let intervalID = 0;

function increase() {
  intervalID = setInterval(zoomIn, 20);
}

function zoomIn() {
  if (width < 400) {
    width = width + diff;
    document.getElementById("img2").style.width = width + "px"; // You assign for example 30px as String
    console.log(width);
    console.log(document.getElementById("img2").style.width);
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
}
```

Example: [Code on Jsffidle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tczdkh5/)

Comment: Now it works! much appreciated!  Though the tutorial has no mention of px anywhere in his video, how does he get his to work?  Video was made Dec 2018 so maybe an update?  And understand about decrease but no point writing that part when I couldn't get first part working.

Comment: It always have been that way, I don't know how he was able to use that property in the way you say, maybe he was using an extension or something like that.
When you are learning some new programming language also checks for the documentation and you could see what parameters accept the methods and objects that you are using, in this case: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
width = 1;
function increase() {
  intervalID = setInterval(zoomIn, 20);
}

function zoomIn() {
  if (width < 400) {
    width++;
    document.getElementById("img2").style.width = width;
    console.log(width);
    console.log(document.getElementById("img2").style.width);
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
}

increase();
```

Example [is here](https://jsbin.com/gexifen/16/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: I have the increase being called in html.  did test calling it as you stated but pic still stays static.

Comment: Well, maybe problem is somewhere else... If you check example link, which I do provide in the bottom of my answer, image do scaling. Problem could be in parent div, for example - maybe it prevents image to became larger...

Comment: Yeah, I was worried someone might say something like that.  I was hoping my code was wrong somewhere but I've quadruple checked everything and can't seem to find an issue :(  Should console.log(document.getElementByID...) return anything?  I get nothing when i try.

Comment: Again, as you can see in my example, console.log(document.getElementById("img2").style.width) printing "234px", "235px" etc...